# How to log webservice requests from ASP.Net-MVC application to external webservice?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, fiddler, webservice-client

I have a webapplication which uses an external webservice to send files and messages. The IIS runs on a Windows2003 Server.

I now need to log somehow the requests which are send by the ASP.NET-MVC application to the external service. In Fiddler2 I just can see the incoming answers from the webservice, but I cannot see the requests which are sent from my application. I need to see the whole XML Soap request.

I've already added this to the web.config

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
      <proxy bypassonlocal="false" usesystemdefault="true" proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

Does anyone know what else I can do?

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to see requests as well in Fiddler.

Comment: What you've done above should work just fine (although you should set usesystemdefault to FALSE), and hundreds of folks do this on a regular basis. You should check your machine.config and the code itself to see if it overrides the proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you created proxy to your web service? If you used Add Web Reference you can create custom SoapExtension to log communication. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapextension.aspx) contains exactly this sample. If you used Add Service Reference you can start with build in [WCF message logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx). If you want customized mechanism you can build your own custom [client message inspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector.aspx).

**Edit:**

Btw. Fiddler also offers application [integration](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/Core/) but I have never used it.

Answer (score 0):

You could activate tracing at the client side:

```
<trace autoflush="true" />
<sources>
  <source name="System.Net">
    <listeners>
      <add name="TraceFile" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>

<sharedListeners>
  <add
    name="TraceFile"
    type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
    initializeData="NetTrace.log" />
</sharedListeners>

<switches>
  <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose" />
</switches>
```

Comment: In the `NetTrace.log` which will be created at your site root.